# How to make this shape in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make this shape in CSS3?

[image: Shape]

Comment: Although you haven't tried anything, check out [this website](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). May be it'll help you!!

Comment: i checkout But i cant understand properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curve bottom side of the div to the inside with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091451/curve-bottom-side-of-the-div-to-the-inside-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, using a pseudo selector of after.

[CODEPEN LINK](https://codepen.io/DollarChills/pen/wrYWZW)

**CSS**

```
div {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px; 
  left: -200px;
  border-top: 300px solid white;
  border-left: 300px solid white;
  width: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 300px;   
}
```