# Inverse border-radius in email template

Tags: html, css, email, sass

I'm coding a transactional email template and it's intended to have a header with a bottom-border with an inverted border radius (see attached image).

Originally I've attempted this with a background image which works fine as long as: (1) The user allows for images to be downloaded, of course, and (2) Most importantly, the email is viewed in desktop because when fiddling with responsiveness (bellow 600px width) things get really messy.

With using an image I was trying to avoid using complex CSS code given the varied levels of support in email clients. However, I'm thinking that it may be a better option to avoid the issue with responsiveness.

I've seen different methods to achieve this curve. For example, over-imposing an absolute element at the bottom of the div with the overflow hidden and adjusting the border radius values there. Not sure, however, if it would worth the effort.

Could you help me find the best way to approach this problem having in mind the limitation of emails.

PS. I'd be OK with a non-curved bottom-border as a fall-back in cases where the client can't render border-radius appropriately.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091451/8620333 (the border-radius one should be supported)

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. It is indeed a very similar question. I just wondering if the solution would work in most email clients. I guess I may just try it and see.