# How does the clip-path: ellipse property work?

Tags: css, ellipse, clip-path

In this documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

The clip-path property used like

`clip-path: ellipse(150px 160px at 100px 200px)`

does work to cut an ellipse at the bottom of the div, but I want to cut an ellipse at the top of the div. How can I do that? And what if I want to cut a concave ellipse and not a convex one?

Comment: maybe this one will help you if you want a concave one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091526/8620333

Answer (score 1):

to make short : placement is set from the middle of the shape

and values can be seen like :

```
clip-path: ellipse(width height at left top )
```

If you set a shape `at 0 0` you will only see a quart of it the bottom and right part of it **from the center** of the shape .

```css
html {
  background:white;
}
body {
  background:black;
  height:100vh;
  clip-path: ellipse(150px 160px at 0 0);
}
```

with vh/vw value you can do   something alike :

```css
html {
  background:white;
}
body {
  background:black;
  height:100vh;
  clip-path: ellipse(25vw 25vh at 50vw 50vh );
}
```

Does this make it easier ?