# is it possible to generate a curve box without any svg?

Tags: css, frontend

i want to code a box like this [image]
and completely using css and other web language ,
not the thing like svg ,
is it possible ?
it is simple when it's cuppy
but the problem is when convex

may some one help me?

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091451/8620333

Answer (score 2):

The .rect::after has `border-radius: 50%` and a very long white shadow that will be visible only inside the .rect since the .rect element has `overflow:hidden`.

For the rect's shadow I'm using `filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #000)`

```css
.rect {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin:2em auto;  
  overflow:hidden;
  filter:drop-shadow(1px 1px 3px #000)
}
.rect::after {
  content: '';
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 60vw white;    
 
  
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```