# How to get a clip path like this

Tags: css, clip-path

I've been looking for a clip-path generator to get a clip-path like the image below, but I couldn't find anything useful. Is there any tool to do that? I used (https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) but that doesn't work in my case.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6kXv.jpg)

Comment: you cannot with clip-path; consider mask .. check the last snippet here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48091526/8620333 it's a bottom curve that you can put on the top

Comment: What do you mean exactly by like that image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
main{
    background-color:silver;
    width: 400px;
}
.clip{
    background-color: #5dafe8;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 300px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0, 85% 7%, 74% 11%, 58% 15%, 46% 17%, 35% 18%, 19% 19%, 8% 19%, 0 18%, 0 33%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.child {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #d2f2f9;
    height: 50px;
}
.clip > .child {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="clip">
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
    <span class="child"></span>
   </div>
</main>
```

Play around with those paths in clip-path and for more help vist [responsive clip path](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/creating-responsive-shapes-with-clip-path/)