# How to create this shape in CSS?

Tags: css, shapes, curve

Is it possible to create this shape in CSS without using an svg? Basically a rectangle with an inverted curve on the bottom.

Any help appreciated!

[image]

Comment: here is a better duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/q/48091451/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mask-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) along with [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient()) to cut off the bottom part

```css
body {
  /* demonstration purpose */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #606dbc, #606dbc 12px, #465298 12px, #465298 24px);
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(closest-corner at 50% 175%, transparent 0%, transparent 99.5%, #fff 100%);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(closest-corner at 50% 175%, transparent 0%, transparent 99.5%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```