# create arc at the bottom of a div using css

Tags: css

I am creating a component using vue 3, typscript and tailwind css. I want to create an arc at the bottom of a div towards the inside. see image to view what I mean.

By using the following code I get the following output,

```
<template>
  <div class="curved" :class="bgClasses">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.curved {
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
</style
```

[image]

I want the arc to be displayed as is but at the bottom of the div like this,

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Here the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091451/curve-bottom-side-of-the-div-to-the-inside-with-css). However I prefer to use a custom SVG.

Comment: Here the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091451/curve-bottom-side-of-the-div-to-the-inside-with-css). However I prefere use custom a SVG.

Comment: Using a pseudo element as in the solution linked to by @valerioageno means you aren’t adding a non-semantically relevant element in your HTML.

Comment: can this be achieved using the predefined classes in tailwind css ?